# how I can know if I have missing CU using "get-spproduct -local" command

Tags: 2013, powershell, administration, upgrade, cumulative-update

I have *SharePoint 2013* with *build number = 15.0.4763.1000* which represents *October 2015 CU*. now we have installed the security updates for December 2015. but when I run the product configuration wizard I got the following excretion on step 8 out of 9:-

[image]

now I read many articles about how to fix this , and many of them suggest to first check if I have any missing updates by running the following command:-

```
 get-spproduct -local
```

now when i run this command I got the following results:-
[image]

But I am not sure what does this indicate?

Do I have missing updates? I mean what does having empty value under the Missing column mean? and what does **Required=True** indicate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Get-SPProduct -local` doesn't actually return whether you are *missing* some updates. Instead as described in the TechNet:

> Returns a list of the SharePoint-related products installed in the farm and the versions of all updates installed for each product.

However to understand why this affects the Configuration Wizard's execution the command's steps should be viewed. The key part is where the version information is extracted from the detected MSI patch and furthermore used in a T-SQL query to modify the `ProductVersion` fields. Briefly yes - the `Get`-command executes some stuff, and in this case at the local server scope.

For complete description of the included steps, see the link of source [#1](http://thesharepointfarm.com/2013/12/the-magic-of-get-spproduct-local/).

To answer your questions:

> Do I have missing updates?

It can't be said yet (although we know that as of 11th of Jan 2016 the Dec 2015 CU is the latest patch we have - The next CU is released tomorrow). To dig this information you could run the following commands:

```
$spprod = Get-SPProduct
$spprod.Servers | Select ServerName, Products, InstallStatus
```

The `InstallStatus` indicates whether there are updates to be installed per server. Possible returns are e.g. `NoActionRequired`, `InstallRequired` and `UpgradeRequired`.

> what does having empty value under the Missing column mean?

Tougher question as the command is quite undocumented, but let's try. By running `Get-SPProduct -local | select -ExpandProperty Missing` we learn that `Missing` points to `ServersMissingThis` property which is part of namespace `[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPProduct]`. `ServersMissingThis` means in plain language `A list of servers missing this product or null if the product is installed on all servers.` So there we have it - the product has been installed on all servers.

> what does Required=True indicate?

While we are at `[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPProduct]` we can also find the `SPProduct.RequiredOnAllServers` property. The `Required` indicates the following:

- `Indicates whether every server must have this product or not.`
- `A Boolean with a value of true if this product is required on every server (in the SharePoint farm) and false if not.`

To wrap it up maybe for others, let's explain the `Servers` column too. The `SPProduct.Servers` property equals to `Information about all servers on which this product is installed.`

If the return is `{}`, that's because we are running the `Get-SPProduct` with `-local` parameter, which means we are already requesting the return from a specific a server. If ran without specifying the server, the return would be `{SERVER$}` where `SERVER$` equals the server or servers having the product installed.

---

As already probably stated in the various articles OP referred, if the Configuration Wizard had previously failed, the Configuration Wizard should(™) run successfully ~5 minutes after running `Get-SPProduct -local`.

---

Stefan Goßner [recently blogged](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/08/09/sharepoint-patching-and-get-spproduct-local/) about `Get-SPProduct -local`. The explanation is flawless and also a recommended read.

Sources:
[1](http://thesharepointfarm.com/2013/12/the-magic-of-get-spproduct-local/),
[2](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/01/psconfig-fails-with-missing-required-error-message-after-applying-cu-or-service-pack-in-sharepoint-2010/),
[3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mutaz/archive/2011/07/22/check-the-build-level-status-of-components-within-your-sharepoint-2010-farm.aspx),
[4](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607885.aspx),
[5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spproduct.serversmissingthis.aspx),
[6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spproduct.requiredonallservers.aspx),
[7](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spproduct.servers.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i am confused now , you mean when i run "Get-SPProduct -local" it will or might modify the registry ?? and does it download or install any missing updates also ?

Comment: @johnG The command does not download or install any updates, it returns the SharePoint-related products installed in the farm including the versions of the installed updates. The registry-part explanation was actually sort of incorrect, I'll update it. More precisely the command includes a part which does version comparison to MSI database where the possible changes happen.

Comment: so i am not sure what you exactly mean by "More precisely the command includes a part which does version comparison to MSI database where the possible changes happen...." ... and why running the Get-SProduct -local can fix any problems in running the product configuration wizard..

Comment: @johnG I think that the explanation to both of your questions has been given in the previously updated answer above. I don't think I can give any better description for what the `Get-SPProduct -local` does besides the one already linked (twice) in the answer.

Comment: thanks again for your help, but this is the first time i face a Get command that modify something !!! seems Eveything in SharePoint world is possible,, so "Get" command will/might modify the registry values waaaaaaaaaaw....